# UITableView in UIScrollView in iOS7

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, ios7

I'm working on a project which needs a paged `scrollView`, and each page with a `tableView` inside. I'd like the `tableView` to handle vertical scrolling while the `scrollView` handles horizon scrolling.

A test project on github: https://github.com/singro/Arc

It works with iOS 6, but when it comes to iOS7, It works only when the `viewController` is not pushed from a `navigationController`.

**some files in my project:**

```
SCMainViewController.h
SCMainViewController.m
SCSubView1.h
SCSubView1.m
SCSubView2.h
SCSubView2.m
SCViewController.h
SCViewController.m
```

`SCViewController` is VC which contains a paged `scrollView` & add `SCSubView1` and `SCSubView2` to  each page.

`SCMainViewController` is a test for `navigationController` with a `tableView`, tap of a cell will push to `SCViewController`.

**Two test cases in AppDelegate:**

One to set `SCViewController` as window's `rootViewController`,

Another sets a `navigationController` as window's `rootViewController` while `SCMainViewController` as `navigationController`'s `rootViewController`.

Here is the unexpected behavior for my `tableView` with `navigationController`:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure out by add

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

to SCViewController

Apple docs:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/AppearanceCustomization.html

> Use edgesForExtendedLayout to specify which edges of a view should be extended, regardless of bar translucency. By default, the value of this property is UIRectEdgeAll.